# Изменение стиля метки при клике на неё

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Необходимо по клику на метку выводить данные о ней и менять её цвет, чтобы выделялась среди остальных и было понятно какая метка сейчас выбрана. Стиль метки задан с помощью изображения, поэтому на выделенной метке мне нужно просто заменить изображение на другое.
Вывести текст получается, так как и у объекта метки и у объекта, который задан в слушателе нажатия есть общие нужные методы (`getUserData()`):

```
@Override
public boolean onMapObjectTap(@NonNull MapObject mapObject, @NonNull Point point) {
    PlacemarkInfo.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    PlacemarkInfo.setText(mapObject.getUserData().toString());
    return true;
}
```

А вот нужный для смены стиля метки метод `setIcon()` не применим для объекта слушателя `mapObject`. Как быть в этом случае и как можно изменить стиль метки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решается следующим образом:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMapObjectTap(@NonNull MapObject mapObject, @NonNull Point point) {
        ...
        if (mapObject instanceof PlacemarkMapObject) {
            PlacemarkMapObject select_placemark = (PlacemarkMapObject) mapObject;
            select_placemark.setIcon(image);
        }
        ...
    }
```